# Highlight a word in a text without .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to highlight text in an HTML document with JavaScript that will be part of a webextension. The use of `.innerHTML` would cause a rejection in the review process. See [`innerHTML` Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations).

I need to highlight text as a link:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

⬇

```js
addLinkWithoutInnerHTML('ipsum');
```

⬇

```html
<p>Lorem <a href="/ipsum">ipsum</a> dolor sit amet</p>
```

How can I pull this off without using `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Can you share what you currently are trying with `addLinkWithoutInnerHTML`

Comment: nothing. I haven't written this function jet. It's just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to look for all occurrences of a string in the `textContent` of the element and use `appendChild` to add anchor elements.

```js
function addLink(el, text){
  let t = el.textContent;
  el.textContent = '';
  let idx, prev = 0;
  while((idx = t.indexOf(text, prev)) !== -1){
    el.append(t.slice(prev, idx));
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '/' + text;
    a.textContent = text;
    el.appendChild(a);
    prev = idx + text.length;
  }
  el.append(t.slice(prev));
}
addLink(document.querySelector('p'), 'ipsum');
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split apart the text content by a `ipsum` regular expression, then iterate over each match: for each segment which is *not* `ipsum`, insert a text node containing the text for that segment. For `ipsum`, insert a `<span>` and assign to its `textContent`.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
const pattern = new RegExp(/(.*?)(ipsum)/, 'gi');
const matches = p.textContent.split(pattern).filter(Boolean);

p.textContent = '';
for (const match of matches) {
  if (match === 'ipsum') {
    const a = p.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    a.textContent = match;
    a.href = '/ipsum';
  } else {
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match));
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: both anwers are good and they solve the initial problem. Thank you. I was just wondering line breaks (`\n`) aren't preserved. I should probably ask in a separate thread.